# Handle order dependence in loops

Tags: php, class, for-loop

I'm making a templating system where I instantiate each tag using a foreach loop. The issue is that some of the tags rely on each other so, I'm wondering how to get around that ordering from the looping.

**Here's an example:**

```
Class A {
  public $width;
  __construct() {
     $this->width = $B->width; // Undefined! Or atleast not set yet..
  }

}

Class B {
  public $width;
  __construct() {
     $this->width = "500px";
  }
  __tostring() {
      return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

**Template.php**

```
$tags = array("A", "B");
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $TagObj[$tag] = new $tag();
}

echo $TagObj['A']->width; // Nadamundo!
```

**EDIT: Ok just to clarify.. *My main problem is that Class A relies on Class B, but class A is instantiated before class B*, so therefore width has not yet been defined in class B. I am looking for a good way to make sure all the classes are loaded for everyone allowing the interdependencies to exist. For the future, please don't consider any syntax errors.. I just made up this example on the spot. Also assume that I have access to class B from class A after class B gets instantiated.**

I know this has applications elsewhere and I'm sure this has been solved before, if someone could enlighten me or point me in the right direction that'd be great!

Thanks!
Matt Mueler

Comment: I don't understand. By what criterion do you want to do the actual ordering?

Comment: See the edit for more details

Comment: Can you add object instantiation order to your tags array? Something like $tags = array("A" => 1, "B" => 2); and sort by order before foreach? Or it isn't possible in your system?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will probably be by making a second pass over the array of tag objects once they've all been instantiated, and calling some standard method (see template method pattern e.g. http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-template-method ) on each e.g.

```
$tags = array("A", "B");
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $TagObj[$tag] = new $tag();
}

foreach (array_keys($TagObj) as $tagName) {
   $TagObj[$tagName]->resolveDependencies($TagObj);
}
```

How resolveDependencies is implemented will vary from class to class.

Answer (score 1):

Where does this $B instance in A::construct() come from? It's not there in scope.

Possible solitions:
1) Static values:

```
class B {
    static $width = '500px';
...

class A {
    function construct(){
        $this->width = B::$width;
     }
```

2) Static functions:

```
class B {
    static function width(){
         return '500px';
...

class A {
    function construct(){
        $this->width = B::width();
     }
```

3) Just in time factorymethod (or object if you need one), if you need objects

```
function getTag($name){
    global $TagObj;
    if(!isset($TagObj[$name]) && class_exists($name)){
         $TagObj[$name] = new $name();
    }
    return $TagObj[$name];
}

class A {
    function construct(){
        $this->width = getTag('B')->width();
     }
....
$tags = array("A", "B");
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $TagObj[$tag] = getTag($tag);
}
```

And if you want a change in B to reflect in A you could always use references instead of assignments. All this of course expects the class definition to be available, define an __autoload() if not, or include them all beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `width()` method in `B` class that you are calling in `A` class `$this->width = $B->width();` (and you should include or sort of use inheritance to use B class in A class)

```
Class B {
  private $width;
  __construct() {
     $this->width = "500px";
  }
  __tostring() {
      return "Hello World!";
  }

  function width() {
   return $this->width;
  }
}
```

As for ordering, you should be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please read my edit for clarification. The syntax error was my fault but besides the point.